# How to get a different screen while using nested navigation with react router?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have defined 2 components(the top bar and the bottom navigation) , the top bar contains a text  and the bottom navigation bar contains 3 tabs, while opening one(of the three) tab I have used react Browserrouter, route and link to display 2 more options , (all 2 options just contain a single line text), when I click one of the three options , it displays the output just below the 3 options(of the tab).This is what it looks like now:

[image: This is what it looks like rn]

This is what i want it to look like:

[image]

Is there any way that these single line output be shown on a different page(only containing the topbar and bottom navigation)?
I am relatively new to react , Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please try to add screenshot or code so that it will be easy to understand what u r saying and what u wnt achieve

Comment: @AdityaShende hey , ive added a few photos.

Comment: Ok so as per your snaps if you click on the options then i should route you to the next page with the following output snap which you have uploaded.

Comment: @AdityaShende yes, option1 to be accurate....

Comment: Sorry but without code it is very hard to tell